# Error run server secondary web farm framework 2.2

Tags: web-services, web-farm, web-farm-framework

it error message:

```
Failed to run operation 'ProvisionPlatform'.  Failed to run method 'Microsoft.Web.Farm.GetInstalledProductsRemoteMethod' on server '10.10.10.155'.  Exception in response stream.  InternetOpenUrl returned 0x80072EE7: Unknown error 12007.  Exception in response stream.  InternetOpenUrl returned 0x80072EE7: Unknown error 12007.

Failed to run operation 'Repair'.  Failed to run method 'Microsoft.Web.Farm.GetInstalledProductsRemoteMethod' on server '10.10.10.155'.  Exception in response stream.  InternetOpenUrl returned 0x80072EE7: Unknown error 12007.  Exception in response stream.  InternetOpenUrl returned 0x80072EE7: Unknown error 12007.

Server marked 'Unhealthy' due to failure to run operation 'Repair'
```

this image my server :

http://www.upanh.com/slider/?e=malihu&s=upload&start=cvs73j6y6ez

help me !!!!!!!